# Fast way for partitioning a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of nearly 400,000 rows. One column contains codes like `R5678.a_D697_E5879`. I want the parts before the first `.` and `_` stored in two separate columns. I wrote some code to achieve this, but it is terribly slow. Below you can find an example. Is there a way for speeding up the code?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

data = {'name':['tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'code':['R5678.a_D697_E5879', 'R5008.f_H697_E5800', \
                'R00778.b_P6_E000', 'L001.a_J847_E5111']}

# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create columns in which to store results
df['lp_code'] = ''
df['lp_code_reduc'] = ''

for index in range(df.shape[0]):
    
    # store part before first '_'
    df.lp_code.iloc[index] = df.code.iloc[index].partition('_')[0]
    # store part before '.'
    df.lp_code_reduc.iloc[index] = df.lp_code.iloc[index][:-2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['lp_code']=p_code=df['code'].str.split('_',1).str[0]
df['lp_code_reduc']=df['lp_code'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

**OR**

via [`assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df=df.assign(lp_code=df['code'].str.split('_',1).str[0],lp_code_reduc=df['lp_code'].str.split('.').str[0])
```